# How to calculate performance growth across varying timeframes?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a problem that I'm wondering if you could help me with, please.

I have a table of customers and their transactions which looks a bit like this:

```
account_number|till_transaction_date|sales
--------------|---------------------|-----
A             |2021-11-01           |10     
A             |2021-12-05           |25    
A             |2022-01-10           |40
B             |2021-09-05           |15
B             |2021-10-15           |10
B             |2021-11-20           |20
```

As you can see, customer A's sales are growing at a faster rate than customer B's.

I also have a table which shows the date each customer joined a certain club (all customers from the previous table are also in this one):

```
account_number|join_date
--------------|---------- 
A             |2022-01-05
B             |2021-12-01
```

What I want to do is to quantify the sales growth of each customer in the period before they joined. So in my example, we would be looking at customer A's first two transactions, but all three of customer B's.

If it helps, the end goal of all of this is to identify which customers were showing the highest growth in performance before they joined the club.

Does anyone know what would be the best way to go about this please? Any advice would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, the best plan I could come up with is to select from the first table all transactions before each customers' join_date, and use this to get a rolling X-day sales total per customer.

```
SUM(SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER ORDER BY DAYS(TILL_TRANSACTION_DATE) RANGE BETWEEN X PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

So if I set it to a 35-day total the results would look like this:

```
account_number|till_transaction_date|sales|35_day_total
--------------|---------------------|-----|------------
A             |2021-11-01           |10   |10  
A             |2021-12-05           |25   |35
B             |2021-09-05           |15   |15
B             |2021-10-15           |10   |10
B             |2021-11-20           |20   |20
```

I could then potentially calculate for each customer the difference between the min and max of their totals.

The problem is that this isn't a reliable method of measuring how much a customer's performance is improving - e.g. if a customer makes an expensive one-off purchase at the right time it could skew their result massively.

Theoretically, I could get the difference between each X-day total and the previous X-day total, then get the mean average of the differences, and this would provide a more accurate way of determining sales growth, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm not sure how to improve this plan, or even if I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely and there's a better methodology I've just not thought of.

Comment: Ideally you should show a desired output, and where you got stuck in your solution attempt.  Is your sales data cumulative?

Comment: You have series of sale values for the customers a (a1, ..., aN) and b (b1, ..., bM). How do you get a "sales growth" (a single number) for each such a series exactly?

Comment: @Randy the sales data isn't cumulative; it's just a list of every transaction that is made. I've added some notes to the original question to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein that's part of what I'm trying to determine. I've added some notes to the original question outlining the best way of doing this that I could think of, but it's entirely possible there's a better method I've just not thought of.

Comment: There is no "better" or "worse" methodology here I believe. It depends on your business need - how to determine this "sales growth" term. You should ask your customer to provide an exact algorithm / formula of this "sales growth" metric calculation.